# Pouring slab but second story sags in old home

Tags: concrete, structural

I bought a two story home built in early 1900s.
It was completely gutted. It had a crawl space so my husband decided we are going to put a slab pouring the concrete 4" higher than the original floor. The home has 9-10ft ceilings allowing for this.

However, we would be covering the original framework left holding second level of the home up. Here is where the problem comes in.  The second story is sagging a lot. How do we jack the second story up leveling it out if we are pouring concrete encasing the wood? What would be the best most cost efficient way to proceed here, ensuring this is done correctly?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. I think you'll find us a friendly and useful bunch, but this question is vague and unanswerable at a distance. If you could provide much more description about the structure, we might be able to offer suggestions. At the end of the day, you'd almost certainly still require a site visit from someone qualified.

Answer (score 16):

You need to slow down and rethink this. You are on the verge of making a couple of serious mistakes. Rather than directly answer your question, I am going to advise a plan to do this correctly.

First, you should not pour concrete around wood support posts. This is a good way to invite rot and an unstable support system.  The floors should be jacked up a bit (1/2 to 1 inch), footings poured before you pour a slab. Trim the posts or replace with steel and set them on the footings. If you keep the wood, they should be set on top of the slab/footing, not in it.

You should determine the root cause for the second floor sagging. Determine if the posts in the basement are part of the problem or if the cause is higher in the building.  You didn't accurately describe how and where the sagging is taking place, so impossible to even start describing what can be done to correct it.

The fact that you are even thinking of encasing the posts leads me to believe you should seek some local expertise to advise you. Don't compound your problems. Get some competent eyes on your project before proceeding.

Comment: excellent answer,  also even if the there was no sagging,   i doubt the framing is sufficient to carry the load of a 4" concrete slab without serious modifications.

Comment: been doing this old house stuff a long time.  LOL